# Unable to retrieve environment variable after calling await

Tags: javascript, async-await, environment-variables

My code have this strange behavior to not being able to retrieve an environment variable after calling an asynchronous function using async/await. For example :

```
async function test() {
  console.log(process.env.myVar) // Output "myVar"

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)) // Or any other async function

  console.log(process.env.myVar) // Output undefined
}
```

I've tried with multiple async function but after any 'await' i can't retrieve the environment variable.

Does anyone have any idea where it could come from ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you post code of function someAsyncFunction()? Because it maybe manipulating the variable.

Comment: Are you sure the `undefined` is coming from you second console.log, and not your `someAsyncFunction` function.  Could you try `console.log("2nd", process.env.myVar)`

Comment: I made an edit to show you that it happens even with basic functions

Comment: So you don't update the process.env.myVar variable at all somewhere in your code? How do you initialize it, from the command line, .env file or something else?

Comment: It's in a serverless application so it's loaded from the serverless.yml file.